# Can you assign an owner to an event & can that person later run a report to see info about their events (in particular a list of attendees/wait list)?

Tags: civievent

I am evaluating civiCRM for a large homeschool coop. Our members teach study groups for the kids. So when we create an event (study group), we want to be able to assign an event owner (aka study group leader) to the event. Then we would like for that person to be able to pull up a list of study groups they are running and see who is registered for it. Having a hard time testing this out on the demo sites since I can't seem to create a login to test things out with a regular kinda member. Thanks.

EDIT: probably would use Drupal if we decided to use civiCRM, since it seems like we would need to use Webform CiviCRM Integration in order to get something else working the way we need.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate if you are constrained to use CiviCRM with a particular CMS or if you have the freedom to use CiviCRM with the CMS that will work best for your needs.  Also, when you have very particular needs it can help to set up your own test environment to try things out.

Comment: Thanks. updated with CMS info. Would like to have a test environment, but not sure my skills are up to setting that up. I'm a bit rusty. Last used Joomla like 8 years ago I think!

Comment: You can get a test site up and running fairly quickly with bitnami ( https://bitnami.com/stack/civicrm )

Answer (score 2):

We did a similar thing for a religious group who were hiring out their facilities and only wanted the hirer to see the event details/participants for their events. This was all achieved using ACL's and groups without any modifications to CiviCRM or extensions. They were a Drupal user too so I shouldn't imagine you would have any issues getting this functionality configured.